# Filtro en combobox con python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Como les va, tengo esta función donde llamo a todos los ***Nombres*** de la base de datos que tengo. Después, todos los nombres que existen en la BD se muestran en una lista de un combobox que en mi caso se llama "Combo1".

Lo que quisiera es por ejemplo escribir en el combobox: ***"An"*** y que en la lista solo aparezcan todos los nombres que lleven las letras *"An"*

Se que ese filtro va aquí mismo en la función, pero no sé como aplicarlo. Agradezco su ayuda.

```
    def Consulta():

      conn = sqlite3.connect('DB1.db')
      cur = conn.cursor()
      query = cur.execute('SELECT Nombre FROM Usuario')
    
      data = []
      for row in cur.fetchall():
          data.append(row[0])
      cur.close()
      conn.close()
      return data    
    
    Combo1['values'] = Consulta() 
   
    root.mainloop()
```

Aquí agrego un ejemplo de filtro a combobox a partir de una lista creada manualmente:

```
def Filtro(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    if value == '':
        Combo1['values'] = lista1
    else:
         data = []
         for item in lista1:
             if value.lower() in item.lower():
                 data.append(item)

         Combo1['values'] = data
    
Combo1 = ttk.Combobox(root)
Combo1['values'] = lista1
Combo1.bind('<KeyRelease>', Filtro)
Combo1.place(x=605, y=19)
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer sobre [el operador like](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/). Y para que el combobox se actualice cada vez que el usuario escribe algo, puedes usar el método trace de la variable de control (stringvar, intvar, etc) asociada a tu combobox. Tienes una variable de control asociada a tu combobox?

Comment: Sin ver lo que lograste hasta ahora, no puedo darte una respuesta si es que la tengo. Podrías agregar el filtro que lograste hacer hasta ahora en la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Hola @DanteS. he logrado hacer filtros en combobox a partir de listas creadas por mi, es decir listas pequeñas. pero nunca a partir de una base de datos. Editare la pregunta para añadir un ejemplo de lo que digo.

Comment: Ya lo resolví estaba muy sencillo jaja pero gracias por la ayuda @DanteS. :)